# Spark on K8s: Job proceeds although some executors are still pending

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am using Spark `3.1.2` and have created a cluster with 4 executors each with 15 cores.

My total number of partitions therefore should be 60, yet only 30 are assigned.

The job starts as follows, requesting 4 executors

```
21/12/23 23:51:11 DEBUG ExecutorPodsAllocator: Set total expected execs to {0=4}
```

A few mins later, it is still waiting for them

```
21/12/23 23:53:13 DEBUG ExecutorPodsAllocator: ResourceProfile Id: 0 pod allocation status: 0 running, 4 unknown pending, 0 scheduler backend known pending, 0 unknown newly created, 0 scheduler backend known newly created.
21/12/23 23:53:13 DEBUG ExecutorPodsAllocator: Still waiting for 4 executors for ResourceProfile Id 0 before requesting more.
```

then finally 2 come up

```
21/12/23 23:53:14 DEBUG ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Received executor pod update for pod named io-getspectrum-data-acquisition-modelscoringprocessor-8b92877de9b4ab13-exec-1, action MODIFIED
21/12/23 23:53:14 DEBUG ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Received executor pod update for pod named io-getspectrum-data-acquisition-modelscoringprocessor-8b92877de9b4ab13-exec-3, action MODIFIED
21/12/23 23:53:15 DEBUG ExecutorPodsAllocator: ResourceProfile Id: 0 pod allocation status: 2 running, 2 unknown pending, 0 scheduler backend known pending, 0 unknown newly created, 0 scheduler backend known newly created.
```

then a third

```
21/12/23 23:53:17 DEBUG ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Received executor pod update for pod named io-getspectrum-data-acquisition-modelscoringprocessor-8b92877de9b4ab13-exec-2, action MODIFIED
21/12/23 23:53:18 DEBUG ExecutorPodsAllocator: ResourceProfile Id: 0 pod allocation status: 3 running, 1 unknown pending, 0 scheduler backend known pending, 0 unknown newly created, 0 scheduler backend known newly created.
```

...and then finally the job proceeds

```
21/12/23 23:53:30 DEBUG KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Launching task 0 on executor id: 1 hostname: 10.128.35.137.
21/12/23 23:53:33 INFO MyProcessor: Calculated partitions are read 45 write 1
```

I don't understand why it suddenly decides to proceed when we have 3 executors as opposed to waiting for the 4th.

I have gone through the Spark and Spark K8s configs I don't see an appropriate config to influence this behavior

Why does it proceed when we have 3 executors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling), scheduling is controlled by these settings

> `spark.scheduler.maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime`
> default=30s
> Maximum amount
> of time to wait for resources to register before scheduling
> begins. 
> `spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio`
>  default=0.8 for
> KUBERNETES mode; 0.8 for YARN mode; 0.0 for standalone mode and Mesos
> coarse-grained mode
>    The minimum ratio of registered resources
> (registered resources / total expected resources) (resources are
> executors in yarn mode and Kubernetes mode, CPU cores in standalone
> mode and Mesos coarse-grained mode ['spark.cores.max' value is total
> expected resources for Mesos coarse-grained mode] ) to wait for before
> scheduling begins. Specified as a double between 0.0 and 1.0.
> Regardless of whether the minimum ratio of resources has been reached,
> the maximum amount of time it will wait before scheduling begins is
> controlled by config
> spark.scheduler.maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime.

In your case, looks like the `WaitingTime` has been reached.